# jQuery UI slider doesn't show

Tags: jquery-ui, uislider

I have installed the jQuery UI slider, but it doesn't show in my code. I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <section id="main">
            <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">



    $(function () {
            ...
            $("#bwvolume").slider({
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 2500,
                step: 100,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#spanbwvolume").val("$" + ui.value);
                }
            });
            $("#spanbwvolume").val("$" + $("#bwvolume").slider("value"));
        });
    </script>
   ...
        <tr class="format">
            <td width="150" valign="top" class="tdlabelNoSize">Volumes monochrome:</td>
            <td>
                <div id="bwvolume"></div>(<span id="spanbwvolume"></span>)
            </td>
        </tr>

     ...
</body>
</html>
```

There is some space allocated in the browser. But the slider doesn't show. My code is based on http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps.

This is what I see in FireBug:

```
<tr class="format">
<td class="tdlabelNoSize" width="150" valign="top">Volumes monochrome:</td>
<td>
<div id="bwvolume" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">slider=Object { element={...}, options={...}, _keySliding=false, meer...}
<a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a>index.uiSliderHandle=0
</div>
(
<span id="spanbwvolume"></span>
)
</td>
</tr>
```

FireBug doesn't report any errors.

Do I miss something like images or something? On the same page I'm using also jQuery UI Selectable (not shown in code) and this is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you link JQuery UI css file?

After I've added jquery-ui.css and slightly  modified your js code the Slider appeared

see http://jsfiddle.net/LGMHP/2/

Comment: You are only supposed to include the html between the <body> </body> tags in the html section of jsfiddle.